# Grant notification access via ADB

Tags: permissions, 7.1-nougat, android-wear

This might seem weird, but I installed a regular Android app using ADB to my Huawei Watch 2 and the app requires notification access which when attempting in app causes it to crash as it trys to open the settings to allow it's access which doesn't exist in the settings.

I just need to grant this one permission in order to get the app to work

Comment: found any solution? (sorry for answer, and not comment, but I have less than 50 reputation :P )

Comment: @mirco no I have not

Answer (score 5):

For Android 9 or above use this:

```
adb shell cmd notification allow_listener com.mypackage.app/com.mypackage.app.mylistener
```

For any other Android version below 9 use this:

```
adb shell settings put secure enabled_notification_listeners %nlisteners: com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.service.ServiceNotificationIntercept
```

Comment: How does one figure out the necessary listener for the app?

Answer (score 1):

adb shell into your device and do

> cmd appops set *package.name PERMISSION_NAME {allow/ignore}*

Edit: I don' think this will work with notification access. Anyway, the command for changing system settings is

> adb shell settings put *setting_name value*

But I cannot find any setting name corresponding to notification access. You can take a look all the available settings [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)

Other alternative if you are rooted is to extract the settings.db where all the preferences are store, modify it there using sqlite and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I need the permission name